# Doubts about the tone of a sentence "I allow myself..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have just written this simple sentence to someone I don't know (researcher).

> I allow myself to contact you in order to request one of your interesting paper, entitled "..."

I suspect this sentence that comes to my mind does not sound very natural for an english-native interlocutor. Could you point out what is natural and what is not ?

More specifically I have doubts on

1. *Allow myself* (It is a direct translation of French. Does it work ?)
2. a probable and unwantted *firm tone* used here (*'order', 'request'* are strong terms in an other context).

Are these doubts unfounded ?

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct. *Allow myself* is stilted in this context.  We might say "I'm taking the liberty of contacting you ..."  Otherwise the sentence is fine from the point of view of tone/register.

P.S. ...one of your interesting paper*s*.